# getting the hyperlink from website

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using Jsoup.
I do a get `document= connect.get();`  and get the html page.

now I write that to a text(string).

I have users who populate these pages.
I know each user name . These pages have the username.
I am able to do a string.contains("username") to check if the user is present or not.

Now my issue is:
I have users with there names in

Tables

ordered lists

unordered lists

in Body

But in all these cases they have in format as:Example

```
<li><a href="http://university.xxx.students.com/grade9/john/117429">2012 academic record</a></li>
```

some  are in table and all..

In the example I know the student name = john.
how can I get all the urls?

==

Comment: I assume not all URLs are like this: 'http://university.xxx.students.com/grade9/<username>' correct?

Comment: yes. some  are in tables, some students have -- href="http://university.xxx.students.com/grade9/john/117429">John </a></li and all..

Comment: I am looking at greping the page . if there is student name in link (or) text extract the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

    for (Element link : links) {
        if(link.attr("abs:href").contains(studentName) || link.text().contains(studentName)){
            studentLinkList.add(link.attr("abs:href"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for this:

`Elements elements = document.select("[href~=(?is)http://university\\.xxx\\.students\\.com/grade9/(.+?)/[0-9]+?]")`

more abstract: `document.select("a[href~=regex]")`

if you already know the name you can replace `(.+?)`, eg.:

`Elements elements = document.select("[href~=(?is)http://university\\.xxx\\.students\\.com/grade9/" + name + "/[0-9]+?]")`

Comment: thanks ollo for the reply.my  input page is a big page with lot of data and link I provided is an example (university.xxx.students.com/grade9/),...I have a page with hrefs/li/..and all. in one if them I know the student name. so when ever I see that studentname I want to get the link associated (the href) that contains this (or) if student name is there in text get the href associated

Comment: You can extends the select with an additional check like `*:contains(name)`. This will find any element that contains the name, there you can get the `href` attribute from it.